# A certain bipartite graph has a matching

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $G=(L,R,E)$ be a bipartite connected graph. I wish to prove that $G$ has a matching for all vertices of the left side $L$, assuming I know that for every edge $\left(l_i , r_j \right)$ that deg$\left( l_i \right) \geq$deg$\left( r_j \right)$.

Intuitively, I want to show how I can construct (possibly, by induction) a matching for all vertices of the side $L$. For a single vertex, it is obvious. But I'm having a bit trouble for the induction step, which got me thinking - maybe there is a simpler way than by induction?

**Edit:** By induction, I mean induction on the number of vertices of the left side $L$.

Comment: Are you familiar with either alternating paths or Hall's marriage theorem? Have you tried a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with Hall's theorem. I did not try a contradiction. Do you suggest assuming there exists a subset of $L$ for which the size is larger than the neighbours (on the side $R$) of this subset?

Comment: That's one approach which looks promising to me. Another is to assume that there is no matching for all the vertices in $L$ and to try to contradict that with an augmenting path.

Comment: This is an interesting result which seems 'obvious' and yet not trivial to prove. Is this a known result or one that you spotted yourself?

Comment: No, as far as I am aware it was already known, yet I could not find this question online anyplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L'$ be any subset of $L$. Let the vertices of $L'$ and $N(L')$ be $l_1,l_2,...,l_n$ and $r_1,r_2,...,r_m$, respectively, arranged in increasing order of valency.

$l_1$ is adjacent to at least one $r_i$ and so $\rho(l_1)\ge\rho(r_1)$. Now suppose $\rho(l_i)\ge\rho(r_i)$ for $1\le i\le k<n$. Then $$\sum_1^{k+1}\rho(l_i)>\sum_1^{k}\rho(r_i)$$
and so there is an edge incident with an $l_x$ and an $r_y$, where $x\le k+1$ and $y>k$. Then $$\rho(l_{k+1})\ge \rho(l_{x})\ge \rho(r_{y})\ge \rho(r_{k+1}).$$
Hence, by induction, $\rho(l_i)\ge\rho(r_i)$ for $1\le i\le n$ and, in particular, $n\le m$. Therefore, by Hall's Marriage Theorem, there is a matching for $L$.

Comment: I have 2 issues with this, I'm hoping to clarify: 1. In the induction hypothesis, the left sum goes up until $k+1$ while the right until $k$, should they not both go up to $k$? Then, when you look at an edge $(l_x, r_y)$ - you said $x\geq k+1$ and $y<k$, but what justifies the e istence of such an edge? And why did we need the sum from earlier? Seems we do not use it.  The second issue: 2. Assuming we reached deg$(l_i)\geq$deg$(r_i)$, why does it follow so directly from Hall's theorem? We want to find a subset of $L$ that is larger then its neighbours...

Comment: Issue 2. We have proved $m\ge n$ and so $|N(L')|\ge |L'|$ for all subsets $L'$.

Comment: Issue 1. Since  $\sum_1^{k+1}\rho(l_i)>\sum_1^{k}\rho(r_i)$ the edges out of the $l_i$ cannot go to the $r_i, i\le k$ and that is why the stated edge must exist.

Comment: Thanks! In regards for issue 2, this I get about $m\geq n$, but how did you deduce that $m\geq n$ from $\rho (l_i) \geq \rho (r_i)$? I can tell that $\rho (r_i)\leq n$ and that $\rho (l_i)\leq m$, but I'm missing what makes it that $m \geq n$?

Comment: As well as $\rho(l_i)\ge\rho(r_i)$, we know that **all** the edges out of the $l_i$ go to the $r_i$. Therefore there must be at least as many $r_i$ as the $l_i$.

Comment: I find this last argument a bit confusing (the last line of your comment: "Therefore..."). We got that $m \geq \rho (l_i ) \geq \rho (r_i )$, and I do know all the edges are between $l_i$ to $r_j$, but why does it mean the amount of $r_j$s must be at least as much as the amount of $l_i$s? How do we know that $\rho (r_n) \geq n$?  ( The series $r_1,...,r_m$ increases in degree, but it might hold equal degree in between..so I cannot guarentee $\rho (r_n) \geq n$ )

Comment: The sum of the $\rho (l_i)$ counts the edges to the $r_i$. The sum of the $\rho (r_i)$ counts the edges to the  $l_i$ and possibly some others so this sum is at least as great as the sum of the $\rho (l_i)$. Given that each $\rho (l_i)$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding $\rho (r_i)$ there there must be at least as many $r_i$ as the $l_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the property you mentioned ($\forall (li,rj)\in E:\deg(li)≥\deg(rj)$) by $P$.

**Claim:**
Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $G=(L,R,E)$ be a bipartite graph with the property $P$ such that $|L|=|R|=n$ and there are no isolated vertices in $L$, then neighboring vertices in $G$ have the same degree.

Assume the claim was true, and let $G=(L,R,E)$ be a connected bipartite graph with the property $P$, let $L'\subseteq L$ and define $R':=N_G(L')$. Assume towards contradiction that $|L'|>|R'|$, thus there exists $L''\subset L'$ such that $N_G(L'')=R', |L''|=|R'|$ and notice that the graph $G'=(L'',R',E')$ where $E'$ are the edges between $L''$ and $R'$ has the property $P$ and that there aren't any isolated vertices in $G'$.
Using the claim, we conclude that neigboring vertcies in $G'$ have the same degree, but there is a $v\in L'/L''$ which has a neighbor $u\in R'$ which has a neighbor $w\in L''$, violating the property $P$ - a contradiction.
We got that for every $L'\subseteq L:|L'|\le|N_G(L')|$, and by Hall's marriage theorem, we conclude that there is a matching that matches all of the vertices in $L$.

**Proof of the claim:**
By (strong) induction on $n+\delta$, where $\delta$ is the lowest degree in $L$.
For $n+\delta=2$, i.e., $n=1,\delta=1$ the claim is obvious.
Let $\delta \le n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume the claim holds for every $\delta' \le n'$ such that $\delta' + n' < \delta + n$.
If $\delta=1$, then we have $v\in L, u\in R$ such that $(u,v)\in E$ and by $P$ we have that $\{u,v\}$ is a connected component as $u$ may not have any more neighbors. We can use the induction hypothesis on $G'=(L/\{v\},R/\{u\}, E/\{(u,v)\})$ and we are done.

Othwerwise ($\delta \ge2)$, we can easily show using the induction hypothesis that $\forall L'\subseteq L:|L'|\le |N_G(L')|$, similarly to the way we have proven the original statement using the claim, but using the induction hypothesis instead.
We conclude that there exists a perfect matching in $G$ and if we remove its edges we get a graph $G'=(L,R,E/M)$ (where $M$ is the set of edeges in the perfect matching) with no isolated vertices in $L$ (as $\delta \ge 2$) with $\delta'=\delta - 1$ and $n'=n$, so we may use the induction hypothesis and we are done.

$$\square$$

**Edit:**
I've been asked to justify the existence of a set $L''\subset L'$ such that $N_G(L'')=R'$ and $|L''|=|R'|$.
We can convince ourselves by observing this simple algorithm:

Set $A:=R',L''=\phi$.
While $A \neq \phi$:
Pick an arbitrary vertex $u\in A$ and take a vertex $v\in L'/L''$ such that $(u,v)\in E$.
Set $L'' \leftarrow L''\cup \{v\},A\leftarrow A/N_G(v)$

In words, at each step we choose a new vertex $u$ from $R'$ which we have not yet "reached" from our set $L''$, we take a vertex from $L'/L''$ that is adjacent to it (indeed, one must exist as no vertex in $L''$ is adjacent to $u$) and add it to $L''$, thus reaching at least one new element in $R'$.
As we add only one vertex to $L''$ at each iteration and remove at least one element from $R'$, we have that $|L''| \le |R'|$. We can now add arbitrary vertices from $L'$ until the sizes match exactly.

Comment: Under the main theorema, how did you deduce the existence of a $L^{''} \subset L^{'}$ such as the same size of $R^{'}$?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain it